# Seed ruby on rails database with html based content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I have rails app that has admin-user generated content, usually large articles created and edited with TinyMCE which is a rich text editor that outputs HTML.  I have about 50-100 articles(HTML code) that I need to seed the database with.  What is the best way to do this?

## Update:

Currently, I have all my articles written in one large word document.  In development, I could enter all my articles into the TinyMCE editor, and save them to the database to make sure they all format correctly and then it would be nice to be able to transfer this data when I go to production and when I need to redeploy without having to re-enter all the articles by hand again, however, i'm not sure the best way to do this.  I will be deploying to heroku.

One method I thought of was creating individual text files, and using rake db:seed to read through and import them, but this seem a bit much. I was hoping for what might be the best practice for something like this.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you just want to put the HTML into the database, or are you trying to extract data from the HTML to put into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Where are these 50-100 articles. In text files?

You could use any of the following approaches:

- `seeds.rb`
- `migrations`
- `rake` task
- `rails console`

Refer to [migrations-and-seed-data](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data), [custom-rake-tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) and [rails-console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) for more info.